# Minimum principle for a simple ode

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega=\left(0,L\right)$
  with $L>0$
 . Consider the following problem: find $u\in H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$
  such that

$-\textrm{div}\left(k(x)\nabla u\right)=f$
  in $D'(\Omega)$

where $k\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$
  is a positive function. More precisely, we assume that there exist two constants $C_{+}$
  and $C_{-}$
  such that

$0\leq C_{-}\leq k(x)\leq C_{+}$

Furthermore suppose that $k\in C^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$
  and $f\in C^{0}\left(\Omega\right)$
  is such that

$\exists\eta>0,f\left(x\right)\geq\eta>0.$

If $u\in C^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$
  has a local minimum at a point $x_{0}\in\Omega$
 , we see that $k\left(x_{0}\right)u''\left(x_{0}\right)\geq0.$

Using a contradiction argument, prove that $\textrm{min}_{\overline{\Omega}}u=\textrm{min}_{\partial\Omega}u$
 .

Help me some hints to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you have tried? What is precisely your question?

Comment: My question is how to prove minΩu=min∂Ωu, I have tried to prove k(x0)u′′(x0)≥0 and that fact is easy for me.  .

Comment: From this, you should arrive at a contradiction by evaluating $-\mathrm{div}(k \, \nabla u)$.

Comment: Could you tell me more about that? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_0$ is a local minimizer, you also have $u'(x_0) = 0$.

Hence,
$$f(x_0) = -\mathrm{div}(k \, \nabla u)(x_0) = -k'(x_0) \, u'(x_0) - k(x_0) \, u''(x_0).$$
This yields a contradiction.